# Preciso deixar uma imagem com link no canto inferior direito

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um site de imobiliária, e preciso deixar um icone de whatsapp que redireciona o usuário para o whatsapp do dono do site. Porém eu preciso que ela seja sticky, fique no canto inferior direito e que a ficar em mobile, ele fique em "absolute" (que fique passe por cima de tudo, porém que ainda fique  sticky no canto inferior direito

```
     <!-- Whatsapp -->
  <a href="http://api.whatsapp.com/send?1=pt_BR&phone=5511997812005" id="link" style="margin-left:94%;">
    <img src="img/whatsapp-symbol-icon-logo-vector.png" id="whats-icon" >
  </a>
```

css

```
  #whats-icon{

    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    float: right;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

   #whats-icon:hover{
    transition: 0.5;
    border: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 80px;
   }
```

Comment: Vc quer que a partir de determinada largura de tela o position mude de sticky para absolute?

Comment: @hugocsl quero que quando tiver em desktop, ele fique sticky no canto inferior direito, porém ao ficar mobile quero que fique absolute (ficando em cima das publicações) e também no canto inferior direito

Comment: Vc sabe que quando ele ficar como absolute e vc fizer scroll na página o botão vai acompanhar o scroll e não vai ficar fixo no canto direito né?

Comment: @hugocsl, então tem como eu deixar ele sticky no pc e quando for mobile, deixá-lo fixo no canto direito da tela, mas acompanhando o scroll da página?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi seria isso, o botão vai ficar fixo na tela independendo da posição na página que a pessoa esteja

```css
/*Botão flutunte do whatsapp*/

div#whatasapp {
    position: fixed;
    right: 73px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: #0d7b00;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    transition: .5s;
}

div#whatasapp:hover {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 140px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 70px;
    transition: .5s;
}

/*Fim botão flutuante do whatsapp*/
```

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=NUMERO" target="_blank"><div id="whatasapp">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/56kfhje.png" alt="Fale Whatsapp">
</div></a>
```

Comment: na vdd eu preciso que ele quando for no pc fique sticky no canto superior direito, porém quando for mobile fique fixed e fique por cima das publicações de imóveis (para não aletrar a responsividade do site)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, está função vai identificar se é mobile ou não, no caso se for mobile você acrescenta tudo que achar necessário por javascript.
Fonte: [Stackoverflow - Identificar dispositivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131677/identificar-se-o-dispositivo-%C3%A9-pc-ou-celular-e-utilizar-um-c%C3%B3digo-diferente-pra/131745)

```
 function detectar_mobile() { 
     if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
     || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
     ){
        return true;
      }
     else {
       return false;
      }
    }
```

Caso não queira fazer por JS, faz por CSS, desta forma estou identificando se o tamanho da tela é de no máximo 600px, aqui você pode editar como quiser o ícone, mas o JS seria melhor para resolver está situação:  "**porém ao ficar mobile quero que fique absolute (ficando em cima das publicações) e também no canto inferior direito**"

Fonte: [W3Schools - CSS @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

}
```

Comment: Neste caso, apenas o `@media` já resolve o problema...

Comment: Ele quer clonar o mesmo ícone, mas no entanto em posição diferente, então apenas com CSS não vai dar pra resolver, ele precisa criar um clone e dar `.append()` do mesmo antes das publicações.

Comment: Com a utilização do `@media` ele consegue alterar posição, estilo, cor ou qualquer outra coisa... Esta função se adapta pelo tamanho da tela, o que inclusive foi incluso no CSS justamente para não precisar se preocupar em fazer funções para descobrir quando se está em mobile. Podes procurar na internet e ver como os sites funcionam quando precisam fazer a troca de logotipo, parcial ou total.

Comment: na vdd eu preciso que ele quando for no pc fique sticky no canto superior direito, porém quando for mobile fique fixed e fique por cima das publicações de imóveis (para não aletrar a responsividade do site)