# desativar javascript em mobile version

Tags: javascript, mobile

Boa tarde,

gostava de saber o seguinte,
eu tenho este site: [www.dinoalves.eu](http://www.dinoalves.eu)
e queria que na versão mobile, ele apenas ficasse com o fundo que esta por tras com o logo e o coming soon, sem o efeito de apagar.... porque eu vi no telemove, e fica tudo tapado...  é possível desativar o efeito javascript na versão telemovel apenas?

Eu tenho assim:

```js
let canvasy;
let ctx;

window.isHidingNow = false;

let wipeyFrame = 0;

let imageDataArray;
let cumulativeOpacity;
let pixelArrayLength;

let alphaArrayLength;
let alphaArrayMaxCumulativeOpacity;

let color1 = '0,0,255'; 
let color2 = '255,8,8'; 

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color2+")";
    document.body.style.color = "rgb("+color1+")";
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
    document.body.style.color = null;
  }
});

let wait = 2000;

let interact = 1;

window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
  // we could use a class
  document.body.classList.add('touchscreen');
  clearInterval(titleInterval);

  // or set some global variable
  window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;

  // we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop listening now
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);

function wipeyCanvasSetup() {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    document.body.style.color = "rgb("+color1+")";

    canvasy = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvasy.setAttribute('id','wipeyCanvas');
    canvasy.classList.add('wipey-canvas');
    document.body.insertBefore(canvasy,document.body.childNodes[0]);

    ctx = canvasy.getContext("2d");

    wipeyCanvasSize();
  }
}

function fillCanvasWithGradient() {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    // Create gradient
    let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvasy.width, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgb("+color1+")");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "rgb(0,0,255)");

    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasy.width, canvasy.height);
  }
}

function fillCanvasWithFlat() {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb("+color1+")";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasy.width, canvasy.height);
  }
}

function wipeyCanvasSize() {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    canvasy.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvasy.height = window.innerHeight;

    imageDataArray = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvasy.width,canvasy.height).data;
    cumulativeOpacity = alphaArrayMaxCumulativeOpacity;
    pixelArrayLength = imageDataArray.length;

    alphaArrayLength = pixelArrayLength / 4;
    alphaArrayMaxCumulativeOpacity = alphaArrayLength * 255;
    fillCanvasWithGradient();
  }
}

function wipeyWipey(x,y) {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    if (interact == 1) {
      document.body.style.color = "rgb("+color1+")";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+color2+")";
      //Make the radius and centre of the circle half of the overall width and height of its container rect
      let widthOfRect = window.innerWidth * 0.15;
      let halfOfRect = widthOfRect/2;
      let grd = ctx.createRadialGradient(x,y,0, x,y,halfOfRect);
      grd.addColorStop(0, "rgba("+color2+",1)");
      grd.addColorStop(1, "rgba("+color1+",0)");

      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
      ctx.fillRect(x - halfOfRect, y - halfOfRect, widthOfRect, widthOfRect);

      if (wipeyFrame % 10 == 0) {

        imageDataArray = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvasy.width,canvasy.height).data;
        pixelArrayLength = imageDataArray.length;
        alphaArrayLength = pixelArrayLength / 4;
        cumulativeOpacity = 0;
        //get the alpha values for each pixel
        for (let i = 3; i < pixelArrayLength; i+=4) {
          cumulativeOpacity+= imageDataArray[i];
        }

        if (cumulativeOpacity < alphaArrayMaxCumulativeOpacity*0.002) {
          cumulativeOpacity = alphaArrayMaxCumulativeOpacity;

          //make a temporary variable to store color1 in while we swap the colours over
          let color1Swap = color1;
          color1 = color1;
          color1 = color1;

          document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('wipeyCanvas'));
          interact = 0;
          setTimeout(function(){
            document.body.classList.add('canvasTransparent');
          },1600);
          setTimeout(function(){
            wipeyCanvasSetup();
            document.body.classList.remove('canvasTransparent');
            interact = 1;
          },wait);
        }
      }
      wipeyFrame++;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',wipeyCanvasSetup);
window.addEventListener('resize',wipeyCanvasSize);

window.addEventListener('load',onLoad);


function onLoad() {
  if (window.isHidingNow != true) {
    document.body.classList.add('loaded');

    document.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
      if (!window.USER_IS_TOUCHING) {
        wipeyWipey(e.clientX,e.clientY);
      }
    });

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
      if (window.USER_IS_TOUCHING) {
        let touchposx = Math.round(e.touches[0].clientX);
        let touchposy = Math.round(e.touches[0].clientY);
        if (touchposx > 1 && touchposy >1){
          wipeyWipey(touchposx, touchposy);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Você precisa identificar que está em um dispositivo mobile e tratar o código, veja essa resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131677/identificar-se-o-dispositivo-%C3%A9-pc-ou-celular-e-utilizar-um-c%C3%B3digo-diferente-pra/131745

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar isso na sua página:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 680px) {
    #wipey-canvas{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
</style>
```

Assim, você irá fazer com que o canvas fique invisível apenas nos dispositivos móveis.

Comment: Como vc garante que o canvas irá ficar invisível apenas em dispositivos móveis?

Comment: @Sam Esse realmente é um ponto importante que esqueci de comentar.  Ao usar `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 680px)` estou limitando o "estilo invisível" somente para dispositivos que tenham no máximo 680px de largura. Mas levando em consideração que basicamente todos os dispositivos móveis possuem uma tela com menos do que 680px de largura, podemos dizer que na maioria dos casos a condição será eficiente.